# How to download multiple gzip file?

Tags: r, gzip, data-analysis

I have to download a lot of files in the format .gz (one file ~40mb , 40k rows).
The file contain a data from another country i would like to choose data only from  `france -> fr` (limiting the number of columns)

I am trying to automate this process but I have problems with unpacking.

The data is on a [webpage](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pageviews/2018/2018-04/)
and I'm intersted in data from whole folder.

I try with:

1. create tempfile
2. dowloand zip to tempfile
3. unzip, read and selected rows.
4. save as new file and repeat to next file.

I would like to ask if this way of think is correct.(the below code will be in `for loop`)

```
temp <- tempfile()   
temp1 <- "C:/Users/tdo/Desktop/data/test.txt"

download.file("https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pageviews/2018/2018- 
06/pageviews-20180601-000000.gz",temp) # example

unzip(files = temp,exdir =  temp1)
data <- read.table(..)
daata[data$name == 'fr']
write.table(...)
```

In this way I created links:

```
dumpList <- read_html("https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pageviews/2018/2018-04/")

links <- data_frame(filename = html_attr(html_nodes(dumpList, "a"), "href")) %>% 
filter(grepl(x = filename, "pageviews")) %>% data by project
mutate(link = paste0("https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pageviews/2018/2018-04/", filename))
```

Comment: I think you'll need a comma in data[data$name == 'fr'] after 'fr' to indicate rows. Or in your second code, you use filter, so you could also use filter(data, name == "fr")

Answer (score 1):

Why not directly read the gzipped files? I don't see the need to locally unpack the archives, if all you want to do is subset/filter the data and store as new local files.

I recommend using `readr::read_table2` to directly read the gzipped file.

Here is a minimal example:

```
# List of files to download
# url is the link, target the local filename
lst.files <- list(
    list(
        url = "https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pageviews/2018/2018-06/pageviews-20180601-000000.gz",
        target = "pageviews-20180601-000000.gz"))

# Download gzipped files (only if file does not exist)
lapply(lst.files, function(x)
    if (!file.exists(x$target)) download.file(x$url, x$target))

# Open files
library(readr)
lst <- lapply(lst.files, function(x) {
    df <- read_table2(x$target)
    # Filter/subset entries
    # Write to file with write_delim
})
```